# How do I ignore positional arguments in python and fall back to a default value?

Tags: python

I'm writing a countdown function where I have a starting number called 'start' and a value 'step' that descends the list by that number. The code that I've written works fine when both of the positional arguments are fulfilled, but I also want the code to revert back to the default 1 for 'step' if it is not called.

```py
def countdown(start, step):
    return list(range(start,0,-step))
```

```
countdown(5)
TypeError: countdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-2bcc97921a23> in <module>
      3 
      4 countdown(5,1)
----> 5 countdown(5)

TypeError: countdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'
```

Comment: Have you tried `def countdown(start, step=1):`, or any other thing that might be reasonably expected to accomplish your stated goal?

Comment: If you want an argument to be optional, then give it a default value in the function definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a default in the function's signature.

```py
def countdown(start, step=1):
    return list(range(start,0,-step))
```